# Hibernate. Different behaviour of same one to one mapping in different projects

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have mapped entities:

```
Entity
@Table(name="user_content")
public class UserContent {
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "content"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "content_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long contentId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "moderate_comment")
    String moderateComment;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    Content content;   
  

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getModerateComment() {
        return moderateComment;
    }

    public void setModerateComment(String moderateComment) {
        this.moderateComment = moderateComment;
    }

    public Content getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(Content content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "content_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long contentId;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "content", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    UserContent userContent;


    public UserContent getUserContent() {
        return userContent;
    }

    public void setUserContent(UserContent userContent) {
        this.userContent = userContent;
    }

    public Long getContentId() {
        return this.contentId;
    }

    public void setContentId(Long id) {
        this.contentId = id;
    }
}
```

I have 2 projects where I use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to `create`. I confused but this code creates database different in my differernt projects.

**First:**

[image]

It is expected and desired behaviour.

**Second:**
[image]

As you can see realtion is missing.

I don't understand where can I search a cause of this problem.

Pleasr help to find.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a lot of time and eventually I noticed that second varian doesnt work because following dependencies were added to `pom.xml`

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
```

After I removed their - relation became a create.